# "a change in ..." vs "a change to ...", any difference?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there any difference between "a change in something" and "a change to something"?

Is that like the former one is a more objective description while the latter one emphasizes the result of a certain action by someone?

Comment: And there are *change for,* *into,*  ... yet to learn about.

Comment: Please do some homework and meanwhile visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

*Change in* refers what is changed, as in:

> There was change in level.

This is the same as saying,

> The level was changed.

On the other hand, *change to* refers to the final quality or quantity resulting from the change, as in:

> There was a *change* from good *to* bad.

This is somewhat like saying,

> It got worse.

Allow me to elaborate further:

> a change *in* temperature *to* cold

would be an example that includes both.

Comment: That's a nobrainer, Sir.

Comment: @Kris I have edited my answer.